# finding nearly identical rows between data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 = data_frame(x = c(1128.4, 1101.2), y = c(124.5, 325.2)

df2 = data_frame(x = c(1128.7, 1100.5, 1527.8, 1347.5), y = c(83.2, 124.2, 
370.3, 325.5))
```

I would like to find rows in `df1` that are **nearly identical** (1% difference in either direction) to rows in `df2`, in a very efficient way to be able to do this for hundreds of rows in `df1` versus a much larger `df2`.

The expected output would be, e.g. a list:

```
L$x = c(1,2)
L$y = c(2,4)
```

to indicate the similar rows in each column.

If the assignment was to find completely identical rows, I would use `left_join`, of course, where the smaller `df1` would be on the left.

Is there an efficient way to do this? (In general I would like to achieve this for multiple columns, as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `data.table`, you will have the fastest solution:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.table(x = c(1128.4, 1101.2))
df2 = data.table(x = c(1128.7, 1100.5, 1527.8, 1347.5))

setkey(df2,x)
df2[,y := x]
df2[J(df1$x),roll = "nearest"][abs(x-y)/y < 0.01]

        x      y
1: 1128.4 1128.7
2: 1101.2 1100.5
```

Comment: I am not a data.table user; could you explain the logic of why (x-y)/y would work and abs(x-y)/y doesn't? I would expect the opposite

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is the most efficient method but one way is by using `Map` passing `df1` and `df2`. Then for every value in `df1` we select the minimum index of absolute difference in corresponding value in `df2`.

```
Map(function(x, y) sapply(x, function(i) which.min(abs(i - y))), df1, df2)

#$x
#[1] 1 2

#$y
#[1] 2 4
```

To check for 1% condition

```
Map(function(x, y) sapply(x, function(i) {
    inds = abs(i - y)
    if (any(inds/y <= 0.01)) which.min(inds) else NA
}), df1, df2)
```